# Native messaging not working from host to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am working on a chrome extension native messaging with the host on Python. The communication from extension to python works perfectly fine. But when I am trying to send the message from the host to the extension, it is not working. I am getting no errors. Even I have enabled logging for the browser. I have tested on Linux and Mac with the same issue. Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

**background.js**

```
const port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("com.google.chrome.uniphore");
port.onDisconnect.addListener((p) => console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError));

port.postMessage("ping")

port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
  console.log('Received' + msg);
  return false;
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((reason) => {
  console.log(reason);
});
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
import json
import struct



def getMessage():
    try:
        rawLength = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)
        if len(rawLength) == 0:
            sys.exit(0)
        messageLength = struct.unpack('@I', rawLength)[0]
        message = sys.stdin.buffer.read(messageLength).decode('utf-8')
        return json.loads(message)
    except Exception as x:
        print("Error", x)

# Send an encoded message to stdout
def sendMessage(encodedMessage):
    try:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage["length"])
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage["content"])
        sys.stdout.flush()
    except Exception as x:
        print("Error", x)

def encodeMessage(messageContent):
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage
    # To get the most compact JSON representation, you should specify 
    # (',', ':') to eliminate whitespace.
    # We want the most compact representation because the browser rejects
    # messages that exceed 1 MB.
    encoded_content = json.dumps(messageContent).encode("utf-8")
    encoded_length = struct.pack("@I", len(encoded_content))
    return {"length": encoded_length, "content": encoded_content}

while True:
    receivedMessage = getMessage()
    if receivedMessage == "ping":
        sendMessage(encodeMessage("pong"))
```

**run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
python3 main.py >> hello 2>> err_file
```

**com.google.chrome.echo.json**

```
{
    "name": "com.google.chrome.echo",
    "description": "echo Application",
    "path": "/Applications/native/run.sh",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
      "chrome-extension://bmfbcejdknlknpncfpeloejonjoledha/"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The [official example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3178.1/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/host/native-messaging-example-host) doesn't use `buffer` in stdin/stdout.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your response but without buffer I am getting an error ```Error2 write() argument must be str, not bytes```

Comment: @wOxxOm With python3 it is with buffer

Comment: Problem with `run.sh`.
Do not redirect standard output.
And I think it can't write files there.

Comment: @pvnarula - I have a question about the code you posted (js, py, sh, json). Is this EXACTLY the same code you're running on your computer? Or did you change/remove something when you copy-pasted the code from your computer to this Stackoverflow question?

Comment: @ThomasMueller Just a minor changes like change the name of my company to echo etc. Did you see anything missing?

Comment: @NorioYamamoto It is indeed writing the files without any issue. Earlier I was using it without any redirection but still not working

Comment: Redirecting standard output prevents messages from being sent to extensions.

Comment: @pvnarula - Did you check that the code still does the same thing on your computer after these "minor changes"? Because I've wasted far too much time on Stackoverflow by pointing out bugs that were caused by such "minor changes".

Comment: "Just a minor changes like change the name of my company to echo etc." - I knew it. In the file `com.google.chrome.echo.json`, you've changed the name to "com.google.chrome.echo", but you forgot to change it in the file `background.js`, where it's still "com.google.chrome.uniphore". Your minor change introduced a major bug.

Comment: @wOxxOm _"The official example doesn't use buffer in stdin/stdout."_ The official example is broken, in more ways that one.

Comment: _"But when I am trying to send the message from the host to the extension, it is not working."_ Works for me. Full disclosure, I am the author of that Python Native Messaging host code.